# nginx pass REMOTE_ADDR to wsgi python web server

Tags: nginx, proxy, python

I am running python web server (Falcon) on port 8000.
Trying to pass real user ip with nginx:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name myhost.com;
#           ^^^^^^^^^^ my real website name here
real_ip_header X-Real-IP;
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
real_ip_recursive on;
set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;

location / {
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    }
}
```

But receiving: 127.0.0.1, so what should I fix?

**upd2**  Now I am pulling 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', but receiving the closest to my network server address, but not my real ip.

Answer (score 0):

We use this headers to pass Real IP:

```
proxy_set_header        Accept-Encoding   "";
proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
proxy_set_header        X-Client-Cert-Verified $ssl_client_verify;
proxy_set_header        X-Client-Cert-DN $ssl_client_s_dn;
add_header              Front-End-Https   on;
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still shows the last endpoint of my internet provider.

Comment: @pmus if you run `tcpdump` on machine with nginx, what source for all packets to port 80?